# I/O file reading issue in java

Tags: java, file-io

I have a file in which assembly language is written `MOV R1,1`, now what I have to do is that I have to Read it  like e.g

First it should scan `MOV,`

Then `R1`,

then `1`.`

But when I use input.next(), it scans like

Mov

then R1,1

What should I do?

Comment: Start by writing some code.

Comment: Have you learned about parsers?

Comment: [Perhaps good idea to check useDelimiter()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#useDelimiter%28java.util.regex.Pattern%29)

Comment: I did, when I write `input.next()`, it first scan `MOV`, But second time when I write `input.next()`, it scans the whole like `R1,1`, but I need only R1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use the `*String.split()*` method to *split the tokens that have commas:*

```
String[] ar=str.split(",");
```

After that, get the two values.

```
string part1 = ar[0];
double part2 = ar[1];
```

In this case `R1` will be stored in `part1`

Here is a working example for you:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class BufferedReaderExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("testing.txt")))
        {

            String sCurrentLine;

            while ((sCurrentLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(sCurrentLine);
                String[] parts = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(parts));
                List<String> splitNames = new ArrayList<>();
                for (String name : parts) {
                splitNames.addAll(Arrays.asList(name.split(",")));
            }
                for (String splitName : splitNames) {
                     System.out.println(splitName);
               }
         }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } 

    }
}
```

testing.txt contains:

```
MOV R1,1
```

OUTPUT :

```
MOV R1,1
[MOV, R1,1]
MOV
R1
1
```

As you can see what the code is doing is: For every line split the parts by spaces

```
String[] parts = sCurrentLine.split(" ");
```

(This will get you `MOV` and `R1,1`)

Then you want to split the tokens you got by the commas:

```
splitNames.addAll(Arrays.asList(name.split(",")));
```

Then you are good to go because you have your tokens separated by commas etc, as you want them:

```
MOV
R1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

The default delimiter in most streams are "space". Although some allow you to change them by a `useDelimiter(...)` method. Take a look in the JavaDoc, of your specific stream.

Answer (score 0):

Solution with Java8 and streams:

```
try (BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("f.txt"))) {
    List<String> words = bufferedReader.lines()
            .map(line -> line.split("[\\s,]"))
            .flatMap(Arrays::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```